# Тайный санта PHP

Tags: php, алгоритм

Здравствуйте.
Есть задание сделать "Тайного санту". 
Опуская задание чтения из файла => отправка имейлов  и т.д. у нас есть строка вида:

```
$str = "test1@gmail.com name1 surname1 patronymic1\n
test2@gmail.com name2 surname2 patronymic2\n
test3@gmail.com name3 surname3 patronymic3\n
test4@gmail.com name4 surname4 patronymic4"
```

Преобразуем ее в массив с помощью:

```
 foreach (explode("\n", $str) as $pair) {
            list($key, $value, $surname, $patronymic) = explode(' ', $pair);
            $final[] = ['email'=>$key, 'value'=>$value.' '.$surname.' '.$patronymic];
    }
```

И с этого массива( можно сделать его не ассоциативным ) нам нужно найти каждому человеку пару для Тайного санты. 
Может кто посоветует как можно сделать? Или имеет решение для этого?

Моя идея была: с помощью shuffle перемешать значение и сделать так что бы:
Первый дарил второму, второй третьем, последний - первому.

При (n>1) возможность дарить самому себе исключена.

Может кто поделиться кодом  или идеей?

Comment: какие то неполадки с вашим примером кода.

Comment: Ваша идея вполне рабочая - перемешать и дарить следующему.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan - писал на скорую руку, вот правильный вариант:
foreach (explode("\n", $str) as $pair) {
            list($key, $value, $surname, $patronymic) = explode(' ', $pair);
            $final[] = ['email'=>$key, 'value'=>$value.' '.$surname.' '.$patronymic];
    }

Comment: Вот правильный вариант измените в вопросе

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan - уже.

Comment: `$final[] = array_combine(['email', 'value'], explode(' ', $pair, 2))`